# lower_bound to perform binary search

Tags: c++, binary-search

Here I have created a binary search function by using `std::lower_bound()`. Like below. This works fine if I pass a `std::pair`, however I want to just perform the binary search on the first value of the `pair`. I'm thinking that in the `Comp` parameter of the `lower_bound()` this can be done but not entirely sure how.

i.e my vector looks like the following.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,double>> v;
```

and I just want to compare the first value i.e the `int`.

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
ForwardIt binary_searcht(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    ForwardIt i = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);
    if (i != last && !(value < *i))
        return i;
    else
        return last;

}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're defining the function as a template when the types are known? That's just complicating the problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom because i need to return an iterator.noramal binary search returns a bool

Comment: Couple notes: 1) `lower_bound` expects the `vector` to be sorted beforehand (matching the comparison function), and 2) the Standard Library supports comparison of `pair`s - `a < b` if `a.first < b.first` or `a.first == b.first && a.second < b.second` - consequently you could use `i = std::lower_bound(first, last, { value.first, std::numeric_limits<double>::min() });` without defining your own comparison (but it'd be thrown by NaNs I suspect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second definition of [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) is:

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare >
ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp );
```

So, you can just write your own function of comparing pairs and use it. Your template function will look like:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIt binary_searcht(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp)
{
    ForwardIt i = std::lower_bound(first, last, value, comp);
    if (i != last && !(value < *i))
        return i;
    else
        return last;
}
```

And, if you want to use it for the elements of `std::vector< std::pair<int,double> >`, you should call it in this way:

```
bool compare(std::pair<int, double> a, std::pair<int, double> b) {
    return a.first < b.first;
}
binary_searcht(v.begin(), v.end(), value, compare);
```

Or, in the geeky `-std=c++11` way with lambda expressions, if you want to have a clean code and don't want to declare additional functions:

```
typedef std::pair<int, double> tuple2;
auto result = binary_searcht(v.begin(), v.end(), 
    [](tuple2 &a, tuple2 &b) { return a.first < b.first; } );
```

Comment: thanks for this the only change which had to be made on my side was that I had to doe `!((value.first < i))` as I only want the firs value to be considered/

Answer (score 4):

You need to add compare class to your function  as it done in `std::lower_bound`:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIt binary_searcht(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare cmp)
{
    ForwardIt i = std::lower_bound(first, last, value, cmp);
    if (i != last && !cmp(value, *i))
        return i;
    else
        return last;

}

typedef std::pair<int,double> mypair;
std::vector<mypair> v;
auto f = binary_searcht( v.begin(), v.end(), value, 
    []( const mypair &p1, const mypair &p2 ) { return p1.first < p2.first; } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom comparison function `comp` and use it with `std::lower_bound`

```
bool comp( std::pair<int , double> &x , std::pair<int , double> &y)
{
     return x.second < y.second;
}
std::lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),value, comp);
```